# Why does a route have different trip_id's (GTFS)?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, maps, gtfs

So, I have managed to complete my route application sans ETA. While I was trying to implement this feature, I came across multiple trip_id's for stops on one complete route and I'm not sure I understand why. Can anybody clarify this for me? Any ideas/comments/suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GTFS models a transit system a little differently from how transit users themselves often do.

- A **route** represents a predetermined (but possibly variable) path followed by vehicles through a transit system.
- A **trip** represents a specific run of a vehicle along a route.
- A **stop time** represents the event of a trip servicing a stop (a vehicle arriving and then departing).

Generally there will be many trips along a route each day—a route that runs every 15 minutes will see four trips per hour, for instance. Each of these trips will have its own trip ID but they will all be associated with the same route. (If it helps, you might think of a route as *abstract* and a trip as *concrete*.)

So if your app needs to generate an ETA for a route at a particular stop, it will need to search for upcoming arrival times at that stop for trips associated with the route. Each trip ID will indicate a separate trip and thus a separate arrival for a vehicle along that route.

Comment: Thanks, Simon! I think this is the second time you have answered my questions

Comment: It is, and I'm happy I could help. Glad to hear the project is coming along well, too.

Answer (score 0):

A trip is a unique collection of stops and, more importantly, stop_times along a route. Having many trip_ids makes the GTFS represent a scheduled service with distinct passing times.

Some routes may not have distinct trip_ids and rely on frequencies.txt, it is far more common that they use stop_times.

If your question is why the GTFS has so many trip_ids and would like to simplify it, I would take a look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/transit-developers/reduce/transit-developers/wP-CjQeArEY) for a series of good suggestions.